# How to include another local.conf in a local.conf

Tags: yocto

I want to change some recipes' behavior based on the image type (release or debug). The best method seems to be setting a flag inside local.conf. It is working, but I have to create two build directories, one for release and another for debug mode. Because all variables and configs are the same, I think it is better to write the rest of the config in one local.conf and have another one just include it, but so far it seems that including/requiring is not working:

My local.conf:

```
include './meta-switch/recipes-protocols/routing/routing.inc'

...
```

Bitbake results:

```
ERROR: ParseError in 'build/conf/local.conf': not a BitBake file
```

Comment: Make sure not to use quotes around the path of the file

Comment: @skandigraun, that's correct, you saved me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is a little bit confused and bitbake could do better here. I suspect you have a line along the lines of:

```
require 'build/conf/local.conf'
```

and bitbake is saying that it can't find a file with that name. What you probably mean is:

```
require build/conf/local.conf
```

without the quotes. Similarly your example should probably be:

```
include ./meta-switch/recipes-protocols/routing/routing.inc
```

without the quotes too. I'd suggest opening bug in the Yocto Project bugzilla about improving the error message from bitbake.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are setting up this automatically, including a relative file is not recommended.

Let me introduce another way of handling what you need.

Using the new feature `multiconfig` you can acheive that. `multiconfig` feature is usually used for different `MACHINE`s builds, but you can try it for your case. This may suite you as defining new config files will add up to the default one which is `local.conf` and this is what you want, here is an example:

1. Create `multiconfig` folder with different configs under your custom layer:

```
`-- meta-custom/
   `-- conf/
      `-- multiconfig/
         |-- release.conf
         `-- debug.conf
```

For example, in `release.conf`:

```
SOME_VARIABLE = "release"
```

and for `debug.conf`:

```
SOME_VARIABLE = "debug"
```

Now, in your `local.conf` add:

```
BBMULTICONFIG = "release debug"
```

This way Bitbake will know that there are 3 configs possible:

- Default one which is `local.conf`
- Release one which is `release.conf`
- Debug one which is `debug.conf`

Now, say you have an image `custom-image` that depends on `SOME_VARIABLE` in order to know what config to apply to some packages or whatever you want to do according to that variable or other variables you can have in the new `.conf` file, or say you configure some recipes according to each config, example:

- `release.conf`

```
SOME_VARIABLE = "release"
SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE:append:pn-some-package = " some_var"
```

you name it.

Now, you can build your image for each config like follows:

```
bitbake mc:release:custom-image
bitbake mc:debug:custom-image
```

and you can test if `SOME_VARIABLE` changes for each config:

```
bitbake-getvar -r mc:release:custom-image --value SOME_VARIABLE
bitbake-getvar -r mc:debug:custom-image --value SOME_VARIABLE
```

This way you achieved the following:

- Keep all multiple configs in your custom layer
- The possibility to add other configurations as well
- The possibility to maintain it easier
- Get rid of the relative include you are doing
- Make it simpler in `local.conf` with one variable `BBMULTICONFIG`

For more info about `multiconfig` check [docs](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/building.html?highlight=multiconfig#building-images-for-multiple-targets-using-multiple-configurations)

Comment: Nice method, I will try it. About this command `SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE:append:pn-some-package = " some_var"`, we can access `SOME_VARIABLE` in other recipes, so what is the purpose of this? Do you add this to demonstrate how to change a recipe's variable here?

Comment: Yes, `SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE` is different from `SOME_VARIABLE`, it is just an example of how to change a recipe local variable from new config just like from `local.conf`